# header(location:) always shows up 403 forbidden

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have some problems. My index.php at `www.quso.epizy.com` always return a 403 forbidden but if I type the redirect path on my own it works. I redirect it to `www.quso.epizy.com/home`

Every redirect in my application is not working and all shows up forbidden why is that?

It works fine in localhost but not in the hosting. I tried asking in the forum but no answers.

I tried using `header("location: www.quso.epizy.com/home/index.php");` but the redirect still shows 403 forbidden.

Here is my index.php

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'vendor/libs/functions.php';

redirect(URL . 'home'); // redirect to authenticate page
```

here is the redirect function

```
function redirect($url, $permanent = false) {
    if($permanent) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    }
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit();
}
```

and config.php for the URL

```
define('URL', 'http://www.quso.epizy.com/');
```

Comment: Maybe I'm saying something stupid but what do you get if you write in a terminal `ls -l /path/to/your/index.php` ? And can you tell us a bit more about your files architecture please

Comment: @Zyigh i get `-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 ashraf_k  admin  133 Dec  7 12:30 index.php` but this is my laptop. im not sure how to write in the hosting's terminal.

Comment: What is the folder structure like? It sounds as though you are missing an index in the webroot. You have an index in the `home` folder, but not one in the actual root.

Comment: Perfectly ok, it's a file that the admin can read, write and execute, and all the others can read and execute. What if instead of a full URL you just write the URI ? (`Location : ./home/`) ? Btw, the server is nginx

Comment: @JustCarty the web root index.php is causing the problem actually. so yea i have index.php in the webroot. the index.php just redirect to /home/

Comment: @Zyigh i tried that too just now. same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've found the problem !!!

If you're looking at the network you'll find :

[image: First Page]

for the first page but then :

[image: Second page]

So if you look at Request URL (**URL de la requête** in french), you can see that you just concatenate the url you wrote for redirection after your domain name. It would probably work if you replace your header function by :

```
header('Location: ./home/index.php');
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
exit;
```

Don't forget that the browser is also your friend and when a request does'nt work, you can look at it ! Hope it helps

Comment: Your header works ! but i don't get it. What do you mean that i concatenate the url? is it the hosting's .htaccess file doing it ?

Comment: I can't answer your question without being too aproximative, sorry. But the fact is, if you look at the first line in second image Request URL (URL de la requête in french) you can see it. Maybe you're 'http://' part was removed in PHP ? As there's a redirection, you should set your header to 301 btw